# Using UINavigationBarDelegate in a UITableViewController which is embedded in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have embedded a Navigation Controller in a Table View Controller inside the storyboard:
[image: embedded]

The Table View Controller has been assigned with a custom class (at the identity inspector) that inherits from UITableViewController:

```
@interface TableClass : UITableViewController
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get events from the UINavigationBarDelegate, specially this event:

```
- (void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item;
```

Obviously inheriting the protocol won't work because TableClass inherits from UITableViewController and **not** UINavigationController.

What can I do in order to get the events from UINavigationBarDelegate ?

Thank you.

**EDIT - Different solution:**

Since the "back" button is being created automatically by the framework I decided to create the button by my self:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

if ([[[someClass instance] stack] count] > 0) {
    NSString *titleBackName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[someClass instance] peakFromStack]];
    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:titleBackName style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(back:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=newBackButton;
   }
}
```

This means that I have assigned a new back button in the navigation bar and when the user tap on it it will perform this method:

```
-(void)back:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Which basically means that I now implemented by my self the pop and the add to the stack of the navigation view controller

**Still looking** for the delegate solution..

Comment: Have you tried simply setting TableClass as delegate? For ex. in TableClass' viewDidLoad() `self.navigationController.navigationBar.delegate = self`. This will obviously make TableClass the delegate for any other controller that will be pushed or pop inside the navigationController. If this not satisfy you, there is another, little more complicated option I can write in a full answer.

Comment: Yes, you should try it and see which kind of exceptions/errors caused the app to crush.